# Writing Traverse Instance for Option

Tags: scala

Working on an exercise from [Functional Programming in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/), I implemented a `Traverse` instance for `Option`:

```
override def traverse[G[_],A,B](oa: Option[A])(f: A => G[B])(implicit G: Applicative[G]):
    G[Option[B]] =
  oa match {
    case None => G.unit(None)
    case _ => {
              val a: A = oa.get
              val x: G[B] = f(a)
              G.map(x)(Some(_))
            }
  }
```

Is this idiomatic? Besides condensing the `case _`'s 3 lines to 1, perhaps there's a more concise way to write this method?

Comment: Can't you just use `G.unit(oa map f)`?

Comment: `oa map f` produces a type of `Option[G[B]]`. Applying `G.unit` would give `G[Option[G[B]]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Never use `get` method on option. In this case you could use `case Some(a)` instead.
2. You don't need curly braces in `case` branches

```
oa match {
  case None => G.unit(None)
  case Some(a) =>
    val x: G[B] = f(a)
    G.map(x)(Some(_))
}
```

I don't know if variable `x` makes any sense in this case. I'd just use this:

```
case Some(a) => G.map(f(a))(Some(_))
```

You could also use methods of `Option` like `fold` of `map` + `getOrElse`, but I guess pattern matching is the best solution in this case.